# How to return an integer value by query object using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

With the below method I am trying to return an integer which is return by a stored procedure it return value 0 or more than zero. In my understanding when the data is returned it is going to be a dictionary (not sure) where as I am trying to return an integer. How I can achieve that.  Below code is incomplete and the code in comment is what I did at first and I realized that I can rewrite the same code in much simpler way. I left both of them there so I am wrong someone can fix me thanks.

```
public int Exists(string plan)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
       var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
       //parameters.Add("@Plan", plan, DbType.String,
           //ParameterDirection.Input, null);
           //I guess I can directly pass param but not sure how ??

        var data=connection.Query("storeProcmem_Plan", new{ ? ?},
               CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //how to return an integer               
        int myvalue= data ???                


        connection.Close();
        return Convert.ToInt32(data);
```

Answer (score 16):

Assuming your parameters are fixed (which they typically are for stored-procedures - the main time you would need `DynamicParameters` is if you are generating SQL on-the=fly to match some complex flexible query) - then the parameter aspect is as simple as:

```
new { Plan = plan }
```

This uses the compiler's anonymous type feature to define that the parameter should be named `Plan`, be of type `string`, and have the value taken from the variable `plan`.

If we assume that the stored procedure `select`s the result (rather than `return`, which needs to be coded separately) in a single row, then the easiest way to read that is:

```
var myvalue = connection.Query<int>("storeProcmem_Plan", new { Plan = plan },
           CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

The generic vs non-generic API switches between typed results and `dynamic` results - both has uses, but `<int>` seems appropriate here. The `.First()` is the standard LINQ operation that translates from `IEnumerable<T>` to `T` by picking the first value (and throwing an exception if there wasn't one) - you could also use `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, or `SingleOrDefault()` depending on the exact semantics you want.

For completeness, if you were using the non-generic API, then you *need to know the column name* - basically, that would be:

```
dynamic row = connection.Query("storeProcmem_Plan", new { Plan = plan },
       CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
int myvalue = row.ColumnName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I was able to get things done.  Now I have question.  1) At the code level I checked that IDictionary object returned so here in your example what is dynamic?   2) If i still get the object in IDictionary while I am expecting a single value how could i get that single value.     3) What are different among single(). FirstOrDefault() or singleOrDefault?

Comment: 1: it implements both `dynamic` and `IDictionary` APIs; `dynamic` is simply the code goo that makes `int i = row.Id;` behave the same as `int i = (int)row["Id"];`; 2: if you use the `IDictionary` API, then you would get the value *by knowing the column name*, and asking for it; 3: `First()` is "at least one row (throw if none)", `FirstOrDefault()` is "first row if any, else `null`/`default` if none", `Single()` is "exactly one row (throw if none or multiple)", `SingleOrDefault()` is "at most one row (throw if multiple, `null`/`default` if none) - these are all standard LINQ operations.

Comment: Okay I see when i had the code as var myValue=connectin.Qeury<int>.. the intelisence said it IEnumerable<T> and said returning a data type as per T..   When I  have query as var myValue=connection.Query("store..  intelisence described it as  IDictionary<string,object> and further said return a list of dynamic object.   Thanks. Actually by looking at those Dapper example I am realizing that I need to cover up a lot , lamada expression, linq , anonymous types and generics.